# "Designated emphasis" on a doctorate

Tags: degree

My university is offering a "designated emphasis" in a topic area, that grad students can add to their transcript.  I think that the idea is that it can provide some sort of signal that the student has a competency in this area, like a minor for an undergrad.

Has anyone else ever heard of such a thing?  What possible practical use could it be to the students getting it?  Why might the idea have been conceived of?

Comment: Check out my related question about PhD minors: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/why-add-a-minor-to-a-phd

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is actually very common in some fields. Economics programs usually have a requirement called "Specialization Fields," "Major Fields," "Field Certification," or something like that ([some](https://economics.uchicago.edu/pdf/guidebook.pdf) [example](https://economics.stanford.edu/files/Grad%20Handbook%2012-13.pdf) [requirements](http://www.princeton.edu/economics/graduate/Requirements/)).

They usually consist of a couple courses in the same area, as well as often an additional field exam covering topics from those courses. Glancing over some requirements, most programs require you to finish ~2 or these as a requirement for getting your PhD, either equally or as a major/minor setup. As you might expect, almost all students do these in fields that they are interested in and will eventually do research in.

As for purpose, I believe that they are mostly used as a signaling and filtering device for the job market. If you look at [any](https://economics.uchicago.edu/graduate/candidates.shtml) [department's](http://economics.stanford.edu/graduate/job-market-candidates-new/2012/2013) [list](http://economics.harvard.edu/files/economics/files/summary_candidates_3.pdf) [of](https://www.lsa.umich.edu/econ/people/jobmarketcandidates) [job](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/jobmarket/) [market](http://www.econ.wisc.edu/grad/placement.html) [candidates](http://econ.duke.edu/ph-d-program/job-market-candidates-14-15), you can see that the specialization fields are very prominently displayed. I think the importance of these is probably linked to some of the idiosyncrasies of the econ job market, such as its degree of centralization, but that's just my speculation.